# ssrs parameters limitation

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008

Is there a way to change an ssrs parameters' data type from the default list that are available in the drop down, which are (text, boolean, date/time, integer, float)?
My problem is that the date/time data type cuts off the time, when we need it to keep the time when it passes the parameter value to the query.
If anyone has come across this problem or knows of a solution any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: r u binding your parameter to a dataset ? Then if your dataset contains date+ time then it will show in your parameter list .The date/time data type includes the default time as 12:00:00 so if if you want to change the default time this article might help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094172/report-builder-set-datetime-parameter

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): you're asking about how to create a new parameter data type, but your actual problem is the fact that the time is cut off (right?).

Comment: In addition to Jeroen's point, DateTime parameters always pass the time to the query, even if they don't display it on the parameter. (In that case the time passed is midnight.)

Comment: Why can't you use the text data type?  Wouldn't that keep the date and the time?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Reporting Services uses a time of midnight as a sort of hack to indicate that the user is only interested in the date.  For example, if you use a time of midnight as the default value of a Date/Time parameter, you will only see the date in the parameter input box.  If you use any other time value, you will see a date and time in the parameter input box.

As others have mentioned, the time component is always there, it's just sometimes hidden by SSRS when it happens to be midnight.  There are several other discussions about this on Stack Overflow, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492169/reporting-services-datetime-parameter-not-showing-the-time-part-when-its-midnig?lq=1).